# SQL Server : update multiple rows with different values

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to update multiple rows with different values, but don't need to match any specific ID.

Of course, both columns on two different tables will have a same number of records.

Example, I have a table `Table1` and `Column1` and a query with list 10 items in that table (*the `ID` is not consecutive*).

```
ID  ItemName
1    Item1
2    Item2
4    Item3
5    Item4
6    Item5
8    Item6
9    Item7
14    Item8
18    Item9
23    Item10
```

Now, I have another table `Table2` and `Column2` that I want to update with those 10 items above.

This also has different IDs, but `ItemName` is blank/null value.

```
ID   ItemName
301    NULL
321    NULL
323    NULL
331    NULL
333    NULL
335    NULL
336    NULL
355    NULL
377    NULL
388    NULL
```

So, I a looking for a query where I can update the `Table2` and `Column2` with those 10 items from `Table1`, and the result looks like this

```
ID   ItemName
301    ITem1
321    ITem2
323    ITem3
331    ITem4
333    ITem5
335    ITem6
336    ITem7
355    ITem8
377    ITem9
388    ITem10
```

Please help.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
WITH CTE1
     AS (SELECT *,
                Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS RN
         FROM   Table1),
     CTE2
     AS (SELECT *,
                Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS RN
         FROM   Table2)
UPDATE CTE2
SET    ItemName = CTE1.ItemName
FROM   CTE2
       JOIN CTE1
         ON CTE1.RN = CTE2.RN
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/49aee/1)

Comment: Really an excellent solution. It saved my day just before leaving work today... heading for a nice weekend. Thank you so much!

Comment: This answer was absolutely fantastic and helpful.  Plus the addition of the link to SQL Fiddle allowed me to alter and test the sample code so I could get it just right for my schema.  Very valuable answer.  Thanks so much for taking your time to write this one up.  This updating of many columns with various values is a tough thing and it is not documented very well so this answer is a real gem.